# nested sync queue inside sync queue not running

Tags: swift

```
let q = DispatchQueue.init(label:"test",qos:.background)
q.sync{
       NSLog("q")
       q.sync {
       NSLog("\(Thread.current.isMainThread) \(Thread.current.name) \(Thread.current.qualityOfService)")
       }
}
```

Why q.sync inside q.sync not printing out ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called deadlock. The inner call `q.sync` waits for the first `q.sync` task to complete. The first `q.sync` task can't complete because it has an inner `q.sync` waiting to be dispatched.

That's the reason why you don't call `DispatchQueue.main.sync {...}`

So the inner queue call has to be `async` in order not to cause deadlocks on **serial** queues.

Comment: making it attributes:.concurrent) also solves that then